# $in operator gives error if pass blank array into it

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation

I have worked on the Go and MongoDb project. In which, I have faced a problem. I have passed a dynamic slice of integeres ([]int) into a query using $in operator. Every thing seems good but when this slice is empty then it return an error "$in needs an array". But i used it as a search parameter and want if i pass blank array then it matched with all.

Note: I have userd MongoDB shell version v5.0.3

Here is my code:

```
var searchedProfiles []int
searchFilter := bson.M{"customer.id": bson.M{"$in": searchedProfiles}}
newQry := []bson.M{
    {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "localField":   "cid",
        "from":         "customers",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as":           "customer"}},
    {"$match": searchFilter},
}
```

If anybody have any idea please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nil` values aren't marshaled as empty arrays, so make sure `searchedProfiles` is not `nil` but at least an empty slice:

```
searchedProfiles = []int{}
```

This will be marshaled into an empty array, so you won't get the error in question.

But this will not give you all documents, this will give you no results (nothing is in the empty list).

If there are no searched profiles, leave this out from the filtering.

Comment: I have edited my question, But the same issue exist. If i have passed empty []int into this then return error instead of empty result.

Comment: Are you assigning an empty slice to `searchedProfiles`? Because the code in the question isn't. Also, as noted in the answer, fitlering `$in` for an empty array will give you zero results, not all.

Comment: In my case, If searchedProfiles have values like [1, 2] etc then everything works well but we its value [] then it gives me error like:    {
    "response": {
        "code": 400,
        "api_status": 0,
        "message": "Error: #126 - There is something wrong, please try again later.",
        "data": {
            "Code": 2,
            "Message": "$in needs an array",
            "Labels": null,
            "Name": "BadValue",
            "Wrapped": null
        }
    }
}

Comment: Yes, I understand your error and issue, and it's because `searchedProfiles` is `nil`. You have to assign an empty non-`nil` slice to it: `searchedProfiles = []int{}`. But again, this won't give you all results, this will give you none.

Comment: If it gives me none instead of all then its ok. But it  give me error. As you say I already have declare it as var searchedProfiles [] int

Comment: If you declare it like `var searchedProfiles []int` then it'll be `nil`, that's what I keep telling. If you assign a slice to it, it won't be `nil`, something like `var searchedProfiles = []int{}`.